# Case statement with subquery in then

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I have this case statement, my goal is to perform different queries according to the variable "equipo"

```
declare @equipo nvarchar(30)
set @equipo='CA10'

SELECT CASE

when @equipo in ('CA10','CA11') then
(select top 100 ReadTime, EquipmentName, ParameterName, ParameterFloatValue
from table
where Equipment=@equipo AND readtime between GETDATE()-15 AND GETDATE())

when @equipo='CA62' then
(select top 100 a.ReadTime, a.EquipmentName, ParameterName, ParameterFloatValue
from table
where Equipment=@equipo AND readtime between GETDATE()-15 AND GETDATE())

else 'nothing'
end
```

My question is: Whats wrong with this query? It keeps throwing me the error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: Seems like what you want is an `IF` statement; SQL Server has no support for `Case` (`Switch`) statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CASE` is an *expression* not a *statement* - which is exactly what you have run foul of: you cannot return results from a `case` expression, only a single value. Your different `when`s return exactly the same values anyway? But assuming your inner queries are in fact different you can use `UNION ALL`:

```
select top 100 ReadTime, EquipmentName, ParameterName, ParameterFloatValue
from table
where Equipment = @equipo
and readtime between getdate()-15 and getdate()
and @equipo in ('CA10','CA11')

union all 

select top 100 ReadTime, EquipmentName, ParameterName, ParameterFloatValue
from table
where Equipment = @equipo
and readtime between getdate()-15 and getdate()
and @equipo in ('CA62');
```

Note: You should really use `dateadd()` rather than `getdate()-15` - to ensure correct results (is 15 minutes, days, hours?). And be careful you are aware that `between` is `>=` and `<=` so inclusive of both boundaries. This can have unexpected results, especially taking into account the time component.

Edit: As your have clarified your requirements you can use an `IF` statement (as Larnu suggested) e.g.

```
if @equipo in ('CA10','CA11') begin
    select top 100 ReadTime, EquipmentName, ParameterName, ParameterFloatValue
    from table
    where Equipment = @equipo
    and readtime between getdate()-15 and getdate();
end; else if @equipo in ('CA62') begin
    select top 100 ReadTime, EquipmentName, ParameterName, ParameterFloatValue
    from table
    where Equipment = @equipo
    and readtime between getdate()-15 and getdate();
end; -- etc
```

Comment: thx for your answer, i need to return 5 different querys, depending of the value of "camion", so a "union" solution is not possible,

Comment: @DavidMenacho then please ensure your question reflects your actual situation to avoid us wasting time! And can whatever client calls this query cope with different structured datasets?